# What does calling as.numeric() do to a lubridate Date object?

Tags: r, lubridate

I am working with an external package that's converting columns of a dataframe with the lubridate date type Date into numeric type. (Confirmed by running as.numeric() on the columns).

I'm wondering if there's a way to convert it back?

For example, if I have the date "O1-01-2021" then running as.numeric on it returns -719143. How can I turn that back into "O1-01-2021" ?

Answer (score 4):

Note that Date class is part of base R, not lubridate.

You probably assumed that the data was year/month/day by mistake.   Using base R to eliminate lubridate as a problem we can replicate the question's result like this:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("01-01-2021", "%Y-%m-%d"))
## [1] -719143
```

Had we used day/month/year we would have gotten:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("01-01-2021", "%d-%m-%Y"))
## [1] 18628
```

or using lubridate

```
library(lubridate)
as.numeric(dmy("01-01-2021"))
## [1] 18628
```

It would be best if you fix the mistake that resulted in -719143 but if you don't control that and are faced with an input of
-719143 and want to get as.Date("2021-01-01") as the output then:

```
# input x is numeric; result is Date class
fixup <- function(x) as.Date(format(.Date(x), "%y-%m-%d"), "%d-%m-%y")

fixup(-719143)
## [1] "2020-01-01"
```

Note that we can't tell from the question whether 01-01-2020 is supposed to represent day-month-year or month-day-year so we assumed the first but if it is to represent the second then it should be obvious at this point how to proceed.

Comment: This is nice and concise, thanks for cracking it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT #2: It looks like the original data is being parsed as Jan 20, year 1, which might happen if the year-month-day columns were jumbled while being parsed:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("01-01-2021", format = "%Y-%m-%d", origin = "1970-01-01")) 
[1] -719143
as.numeric(as.Date("0001-01-20", origin = "1970-01-01")) 
[1] -719143
```

Is there a way to share an example of the raw data as you have it? e.g. `dput(MY_DATA[1:10, DATE_COL])`

---

EDIT: -719143 is about 1970 years of days, which can't be a coincidence, given that many date/time formats use 1970 as a baseline. I wonder if `01-01-2021` is being interpreted as the numeric formula equal to `-2021` and so we're looking at perhaps `-2021` seconds/days/[?] before year zero, which would be about -1970 years before the epoch...

```
-719143/(365)
[1] -1970.255
```

For instance, we can get something close with:

```
as.numeric(as.Date("0000-01-01", origin = "1970-01-01"))
[1] -719528
```

---

Original answer:

R treats a string describing a date as text:

```
x <- "01-01-2021"
class(x)
[1] "character"
```

We can convert it to a `Date` data type using these two equivalent commands:

```
base_dt <- as.Date(x, "%m-%d-%Y")   # base R version
lubridt <- lubridate::mdy(x)        # convenience lubridate function

identical(base_dt, lubridt)
[1] TRUE
```

Under the hood, a `Date` object in R is a numeric value with a flag telling R it's a date:

```
> typeof(lubridt)                  # What general type of data is it? 
[1] "double"                       # --> numeric, stored as a double
> as.numeric(lubridt)
[1] 18628
 > class(lubridt)                  # Does it have any special class attributes?      
[1] "Date"                         # --> yes, it's a Date
 > dput(lubridt)                   # How would we construct it from scratch?
 structure(18628, class = "Date")  # --> by giving 18628 a Date attribute
```

In R, a Date is encoded as the number of days since 1970 began:

```
 > as.Date("1970-01-1") + as.numeric(lubridt)
 [1] "2021-01-01"
```

We could convert it back to the original text using:

```
format(base_dt, "%m-%d-%Y")
[1] "01-01-2021"
identical(x, format(base_dt, "%m-%d-%Y"))
[1] TRUE
```